# Accessing Session in the ServiceStack Razor View

Tags: session, razor, servicestack

I am trying to access the session inside a ServiceStack Razor View (Partial).  In this case I am just trying to render our the menu which exists in the session.

```
@(new HtmlString(this.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>().MenuHtmlString))
```

I get this error:

Response Status

> Error Code
>           NullReferenceException
>       Message
>           Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       Stack Trace
>           [BOPBasicInfo1VM: 1/31/2014 9:46:45 PM]: [REQUEST: {QuoteNumber:1,AgencyId:0,Errors:[],IsValid:False}]
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at ASP._*BOPBasicInfo1VM.Execute() at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage`1.WriteTo(StreamWriter writer) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPageWithLayout(IRequest
>   httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object model, IRazorView page, Func`1
>   layout) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ResolveAndExecuteRazorPage(IRequest
>   httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object model, RazorPage razorPage) at
>   ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ProcessRequest(IRequest
>   httpReq, IResponse httpRes, Object dto) at
>   ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.<>c*_DisplayClass2.b__0(IViewEngine
>   x) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate) at
>   ServiceStack.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequest request,
>   Object response, IResponse httpRes)

Am I trying to access the session correctly? Any ideas as to why this is failing?

As far as I know there is no break point/debug support in the SS Razor Views, has that changed with the latest version v4.0.8.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the

```
@(new HtmlString())
```

instead of the

```
this.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>().MenuHtmlString
```

The way that I figured that out was by creating a static method on a class and passing "this" into it so that I could debug.

```
    public static HtmlString GetMenu(ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage page)
    {
        return new HtmlString(page.SessionAs<FMIC.DTOs.Entities.CustomUserSession>().MenuHtmlString);
    }
```

And calling it like this from the view.

```
@(ViewPageExtensions.GetMenu(this))
```

I will also add a comment from Demis (mythz) from the ServiceStack Forums

> To help with debugging I would call your own method from Razor views
>   so you can put a breakpoint and inspect the values passed in.
>
> You should also hopefully be able to debug v4.09 source code using the
>   source symbols published with NuGet, some instructions: 
>   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#wiki-debugging-source-symbols-in-nuget-packages